# How to create a 2D array from a 1D array and a 3D array:

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to create a 2D array from a 1D array and a 3D array:

```
pr = np.array([100, 50, 20]).reshape(-1,1)
```

The 3D array:

```
arr = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [9, 10, 11]], [[12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]]])
```

I can perform the tasks, manually as follows:

```
pr = np.array([100, 50, 20]).reshape(-1,1)
arr = np.array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [9, 10, 11]], [[12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17]]])

po = arr[0,:,:].flatten().reshape(-1,1)

p1 = np.vstack([pr[0]]*po.size)
p2 = np.vstack([pr[1]]*po.size)
p3 = np.vstack([pr[2]]*po.size)

p_arr = np.vstack((p1,p2,p3))

arr_1 = arr.flatten().reshape(-1,1)

data = np.hstack((p_arr,arr_1))
```

This approach means that, I have to update the code whenever the size of "pr" changes. Please is there a better way to do this that would not require me to update the code when the size of "pr" changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually broadcast `pr` to the same shape as `arr`, and then stack them by column:

```
>>> pr = np.array([100, 50, 20])
>>> arr = np.array([[[1, 2, 3],
...                  [4, 5, 6]],
...                 [[7, 8, 9], 
...                  [9, 10, 11]],
...                 [[12, 13, 14],
...                  [15, 16, 17]]])
>>> np.column_stack([np.broadcast_to(pr[:, None, None], arr.shape).ravel(),
...                  arr.ravel()])
array([[100,   1],
       [100,   2],
       [100,   3],
       [100,   4],
       [100,   5],
       [100,   6],
       [ 50,   7],
       [ 50,   8],
       [ 50,   9],
       [ 50,   9],
       [ 50,  10],
       [ 50,  11],
       [ 20,  12],
       [ 20,  13],
       [ 20,  14],
       [ 20,  15],
       [ 20,  16],
       [ 20,  17]])
```

A simple `repeat` can also directly generate flattened array:

```
>>> np.column_stack([pr.repeat(arr.size // pr.size), arr.ravel()])
array([[100,   1],
       [100,   2],
       [100,   3],
       [100,   4],
       [100,   5],
       [100,   6],
       [ 50,   7],
       [ 50,   8],
       [ 50,   9],
       [ 50,   9],
       [ 50,  10],
       [ 50,  11],
       [ 20,  12],
       [ 20,  13],
       [ 20,  14],
       [ 20,  15],
       [ 20,  16],
       [ 20,  17]])
```